# Windows10 Ubuntu 18.04 dual boot problem

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

I’m trying to install a dual boot Windows10 + Ubuntu18.04 on my new Windows laptop. Unfortunately, the Ubuntu installer is not able to see the “unallocated” partition I’ve created for Ubuntu.

In terms of steps:

1. I created an additional partition and it’s “unallocated” (snapshot below):

[image: snapshot 1]

2. Created an Ubuntu18.04 bootable USB using Rufus.
3. During the installation Ubuntu doesn’t see the created partition in 1 (snapshot below):

[image: snapshot 2]

Answer (score 0):

Formatting a partition in Windows and assigning a drive letter to it solved this problem for me.
Ubuntu then uses that partition and creates additional ones.

Comment: Unfortunately this approach didn't work for me.